# Append Historical Remarks in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

some background here:

- I am using PowerApps to customise a SharePoint New Item form for a list
- I have tidy up my form and for remarks column, I would like the PowerApps to append previous remarks (including the user, date, time, and comments made) for ease of reference - just like how the default SharePoint form would normally do
- However in PowerApps there doesn't seem to have this feature built in instead
  Any comments or suggestions on how I can enable this feature? Thank you.

Have tried adding text item into the remarks field, however there is no option in PowerApps that allows me to display historical remarks like default SharePoint does.

In terms of outcome expectation, it would be something like this on PowerApps (visually it looks like how it does on SharePoint)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy or efficient way of achieving this. In theory you can create a Power Automate flow that:

- you call from your app, supplying the ID of the SharePoint item as parameter
- the flow will then have to get the current version number of the item
- then you have to create a descending integer array from that number back to 1
- you can then use Apply to each on all version numbers
- within the loop use the SharePoint REST API to get the version by id and number
- collect the user, timestamp and the comment itself into an object array
- at the end of the flow you can respon to PowerApps with a json as text
- in PowerApps you can use the experimental ParseJSON function to make sense of the returned data

Well... this sums up why most developers simply use separate lists for remarks.